# Изменить имя события

Tags: c#, события

есть строка с именем кнопки, надо сформировать имя события

```
string butstr = "buttonExit";
button.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

как сменить имя события button1_Click на buttonExit_Click ?

Comment: Взяли и переименовали, если так прям хочется, это простые методы. Вопрос то в чем? И при чем тут имя кнопки?

Comment: Не знаете как текст в текстовом редакторе редактировать, или что?

Comment: надо было просто задать соответствующий аргумент - (EventHandler onclick) и уже после добавлять в button.Click += onclick; иногда очевидное решение не столь очевидно